# How to get the numbers of the last 6 months only using mysql (no php)

Tags: mysql

Something like:

```
SELECT MONTH(*date?*)
  FROM 
   //Not sure what goes here
LIMIT 0,6
```

I know its simple, but I want to know how to get a list of the last six months in case i ever need to Join to it. Useful if getting past data and using:

> IFNULL(data, 0)

Comment: Do you have a _date_ or _timestamp_ column in your table? If yes use a WHERE clause to get the rows you want, if not I don't think that mysql saves date/time data to records in its meta-data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select month(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)) month_6,
       month(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH)) month_5,
       month(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 4 MONTH)) month_4,
       month(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) month_3,
       month(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)) month_2,
       month(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) month_1
```

OUTPUT

```
month_6 month_5 month_4 month_3 month_2 month_1
      9      10      11      12       1       2
```

If you want it to include the current month, then just start with 5 and go to 0 instead of 6 to 1.

If you want rows, do this:

```
select        month(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH))
union  select month(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH))
union  select month(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 4 MONTH))
union  select month(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH))
union  select month(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH))
union  select month(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

OUTPUT

```
9
10
11
12
1
2
```

Comment: this will put it in columns and not rows. it works, but he might want rows

Comment: @ocdcoder: yep. Also this is a hardcoded solution and it should involve some programming language to generate the query, in case if op needs not constant amount of months each time

Comment: Yea I would like to join to them, so I would need them in rows.

Comment: Perfect! That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks you. Seems so simple.

Comment: Just curious how your solution would work if 6 months requirement is changed to 50 :-)

Comment: @zerkms: see my answer :) and it doesn't have to be generated in a programming language. It just has to take better advantage of its features. Databases are fine to use for things like this.

Answer (score 1):

Not that this is really any better than a solution like dcp's but it gives you a bit more control over the months. You can create a table with 1-6:

```
    create table intervals ( i int );
    insert into intervals values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6);
```

and then do:

```
    select month(date_sub(now(), interval intervals.i month)) month from intervals;
```

Comment: I deleted exactly the same answer :-) Will undelete it for a moment then. Get my +1 for doing it *right* ;-)